# Object Instantiation Calling Constructor Too Many Times

Tags: c++

I have a templated class that I am trying to declare as a two-dimensional templated object. When I declare my 2D object, my constructor is being called something like 15 times, and for what I think are related reasons my destructor is trying to delete memory that was not allocated. I suspect it has to do with the way I am trying to pass another instance of my class as a template parameter...

A probably related issue is that while main is making those excessive constructor calls, my destructor is called and I get a malloc error. I can't seem to find where I am allocating memory without the new operator...to my understanding, every possible instance of a My_vector should assign `new` memory to array.

Why is my constructor being called repeatedly during that first line within my main function?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "My_vector.h"

int main() {
    My_vector<My_vector<bool>> board; //this is where I get 15 calls to the constructor

    My_vector<bool> row(4, 0);
    board.push_back(row);
}
```

My_vector.h

```
#include <cstring>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename Type>
class My_vector {
private:
    Type* array;
    int vector_capacity;
    int vector_size;
public:
    //Constructors
    My_vector(int n = 0) {              //keeps getting called
        vector_capacity = n + 10;
        array = new Type[vector_capacity];
        vector_size = 0;
    }

    My_vector(int n, Type value) {
        initialize(n + 10);
        for ( ; n > 0; n--) {
            push_back(value);
        }
    }

    My_vector(std::initializer_list<Type> list) {
        initialize(list.size() + 10);
        memcpy(array, list.begin(), sizeof(Type) * list.size());
    }

    //Destructor
    ~My_vector() {delete [] array; array = nullptr;} //get a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error in the same line that creates the excessive constructor calls

    //Accessors
    int size() const {return vector_size;}
    int capacity() {return vector_capacity;}
    Type& at(int const) const;

    //Mutators
    void push_back(Type const& val);
    void increase_capacity();
    void initialize(int n = 10);
    void erase(int);
    void resize(int, Type val = Type());
    void assign(std::initializer_list<Type> list);
};

template <typename Type>
void My_vector<Type>::push_back(Type const& val) {
    if (size() == capacity()) {
        increase_capacity();
    }
    array[vector_size++] = val;
}

template <typename Type>
void My_vector<Type>::increase_capacity() {
    Type* temp_array = new Type[1.5 * capacity()];
    memcpy(temp_array, array, size() * sizeof(Type));
    delete [] array;
    array = temp_array;
    vector_capacity = 1.5 * capacity();
}

template <typename Type>
Type& My_vector<Type>::at(int const index) const {
    return *(array + index);
}

template <typename Type>
void My_vector<Type>::initialize(int n) {
    vector_capacity = n;
    array = new Type[vector_capacity];
    vector_size = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call gets you to the first constructor:

```
My_vector(int n = 0) {              //keeps getting called
```

Inside this constructor, you create 10 more `My_vector<bool>` objects:

```
    vector_capacity = n + 10;
    array = new Type[vector_capacity];
```

Again - the first entry is for the board object - My_vector of My_vector object.

The rest of the entries in the same constructor are for each of the 10 new My_vector of bool objects that you make in the code above.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you so much...I can fix this now. Your answer was the first so I will accept it. Thanks again for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting the constructor called 11 times

1 time for this line: `My_vector<My_vector<bool>> board;` in the main

10 times for this line:  `array = new Type[vector_capacity];` in the constructor

The second line calls the constructor again 10 times because vector_capacity is by default 10

Answer (score 1):

`array = new Type[vector_capacity];` Calls the default constructor for every object created in that array.  Since you have `My_vector<My_vector<bool>> board;` this is expected, it calls the constructor on each internal `My_vector`.